# Core Location returning 00

Tags: iphone, delegates, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

Here's the full method, I didn't put the second half originally because I know it works:

```
 -(void)showDirections
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    NSNumber *myLatitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.latitude];
    NSNumber *myLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.longitude];
    double myLatitude2 = [myLatitude doubleValue];
    double myLongitude2 = [myLongitude doubleValue];


    NSArray *array = [dataHold objectForKey:@"Subtree"];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:4]];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:5]];
    double clubLatitude = [latitude doubleValue];
    double clubLongitude = [longitude doubleValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { myLatitude2, myLongitude2};    
    CLLocationCoordinate2D destination = { clubLatitude, clubLongitude};        
    NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f",start.latitude, start.longitude, destination.latitude, destination.longitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];

}
```

Comment: Okay, why in the world are you boxing/unboxing there? It seems like you might need a refresher on where to use `NSNumber` :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1) You are doing a `NSNumber` box/unbox cycle that has no use whatsoever

2) **Core Location is asynchronous, therefore you cannot return the user's location straight away, you must use the delegate method(s) to retrieve the location if/when it is available.**

Here's an example of how it *should* work:

```
 -(void)showDirections
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [newLocation coordinate];
    NSArray *array = [dataHold objectForKey:@"Subtree"];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:4]];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:5]];
    double clubLatitude = [latitude doubleValue];
    double clubLongitude = [longitude doubleValue];
    NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude, clubLatitude, clubLongitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];
}
```

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    //NSLog(@"%@",coordinate);
 [event setLatitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.latitude]];
 [event setLongitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.longitude]];

Answer (score 1):

The fourth line of your code is where the problem begins. You cannot get the location instantly, you will need to wait until the location services notify the delegate that a location is available. I will add some comments to your code to explain:

```
-(void)showDirections
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    // this is not where you should be looking 
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];

    // the rest of this function is not included in this example ...
}
```

Since you set the delegate as "self", the current class but implement the "[CLLocationManagerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html)" protocol, which defines the following two functions:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation { /* */ }
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error { /* */ }
```

That is where you will get a location provided to you.

Dont forget to update your class definition like so:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
```

And as a side note, it seems like you do not fully understand delegates and the purpose that they serve, which is fine if you are new to Objective-C, but getting more familiar with them will certainly make your life a bit easier.

Some other helpful stuff:

- [A CoreLocation Tutorial (covers what you are trying to do)](http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/)

Comment: now when I re-enter the program, the view that loads is the view that sends it back to the map application. I'm caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thats a design decision and not related to core location. In the UIApplicationDelegate (you would have implemented some of its functions in the application delegate) you can use "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" to see if the application was launched with a URL, and if it was then dont launch it again :)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: Thanks Nippy, I made a short term solve. TO be honest, I don't fully understand delegates and I find apple documentation difficult for new programmers. Any better "dumbed down" resources?

Comment: @Eric. My Pleasure. I couldn't find anything online to explain delegates in an easy way. Just think of it like this ... a UITextField (text box) can operate perfectly fine without a delegate ... it can display text, get text from the user, etc ... but whenever the user taps the control to start inputing text it will check if there is a delegate, and IF that delegate implements (not required) the "DidEntertextField" function (for example) then it will can  that function. Its just an easy way for you to extend the functionality of the control. I hope that made sense to you.